# How to made field type ‘Document (filename)’ can only be opened and viewed on other tab? [Scriptcase]

Tags: javascript, php, html, scriptcase

I'm using Scriptcase. I have field type ‘Document (filename)’, field name is attachment. When it have document on it, I want when I clicked the doc, it only can be opened in new tab and viewed it. The default setting is when you clicked the file, it will be opened in new tab and automatically downloaded it. I don’t want it to be downloaded. Is there any method how to do it?

[image: attachment]